# How to Pass Props and Navigation in below react native code

Tags: typescript, react-native

I am working on react native using typescript.

How to pass Navigation in interface, and below code snippet is Functional component or class component. What Reach.FC indicates ?

```
interface HomeScreenProps {}

export const HomeScreen: React.FC<HomeScreenProps> = ({}) => (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
    <Text>Home!</Text>
  </View>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the types provided by `@react-navigation/native` and `@react-navigation/stack`;

```
import { RouteProp } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { StackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/stack';

type RootParams = {
  Home: undefined;
};

type HomeScreenRouteProps = RouteProp<RootParams, 'Home'>;

type HomeScreenNavigationProps = StackNavigationProp<
  RootParams,
  'Home'
>;

interface HomeScreenProps = {
  route: HomeScreenRouteProps;
  navigation: HomeScreenNavigationProps;
};

export const HomeScreen: React.FC<HomeScreenProps> = ({ navigate, route }) => (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
    <Text>Home!</Text>
  </View>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the `useNavigation` hook without passing it around in props. 
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/